# How TryParse method works?

Tags: c#

I have the following code.

```
using System;

class program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string StrNumber = "100TG";
        int result = 0;

        bool IsConversionSuccessful = int.TryParse(StrNumber, out result);

        if (IsConversionSuccessful)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that TryParse method tries to convert StrNumber(100TG) into an integer.

And if it succeeds, it's going to save converted value into a result variable and return true for boolean.
And if it fails, a result value will remain as 0 and it will return false for boolean.

My question is that no matter what kind of boolean value IsConversionSuccessful variable gets, wouldn't "if(IsConversionSuccessful)" get activated? Am I misunderstanding TryParse Method?

Comment: Yeah, you already admit the variable could be false, so isn't it obvious the `else` block is enterable? Or are you asking this because the use of a constant string value means `TryParse` will always return the same value in this code?

Comment: Could you tell me as to why if(IsConversionSuccessful) won't run when IsConversionSuccessful is false?

Comment: @jelly The body of an `if` executes only when the condition evaluates to `true`. Look at the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Are you interested in whether `if(IsConversionSuccessful)` gets executed or whether its' body gets executed?

Comment: I didn't know that 'if' executes only when the condition is true. I thought it works on every condition. Thank you for your help Jafar :)

Comment: @jelly consider marking an answer.

Comment: @Jafar I didn't see your previous question about if(IsConversionSuccessful) or its body getting executed. Could you explain it please?

Comment: The `if()` it self gets executed. The body following depends on the result of the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `IsConversionSuccessful` gets to be `false`, then the condition `if(IsConverstionSuccessful)` evaluates to `if(false)`. Hence, the body of that `if` does not execute.

The `TryParse` method does not determine the execution of the next line in your program. It simply tells you whether the conversion from `string` to `int` was successful or not by returning a boolean value.

The lines following `TryParse` is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

As you clearly have pointed out,

```
bool IsConversionSuccessful = int.TryParse(StrNumber, out result);
```

Will set IsConversionSuccessful to true/false based on how the method parsed the number.

If statements in themself evaluate something and always get a boolean answer, true or false. This is because if statements act like binary branch trees. They work like this: [image]

When you evaluate if(A), which in your case is

```
if (IsConversionSuccessful)
```

The processor decides on a path to take and execution after that depends on the decision the processor made. Note that even excluding the else branch, an empty else branch simply points back to the "..." that comes after the if statement.

Comment: Could you tell me as to why if(IsConversionSuccessful) won't run when IsConversionSuccessful is false?