# Basic C# Program Involving functions not working

Tags: c#, function, procedure

I am a beginner in C# and was creating a program with functions but unfortunately am very confused how to return the value in the function to the main program.

I have researched for other similar questions but i cannot find the answer as it is very basic.

```
class Program
{
    public int answer = 0;
    public int column = 0;
    public int UserInput;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        BinaryInput(int UserInput);
        Console.WriteLine(UserInput);
        
    }

    static int BinaryInput (ref int UserInput)
    {
        UserInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return UserInput;

    } 

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a return value and a ref parameter at the same time for the same thing is completely unnecessary.

Just choose a method like this:

```
static int GetBinaryInput()
{ 
  return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int UserInput = GetBinaryInput();
  Console.WriteLine(UserInput);
}
```

Or like that, prefering `out` here:

```
static void GetBinaryInput(out int UserInput)
{ 
  UserInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  GetBinaryInput(out var UserInput);
  Console.WriteLine(UserInput);
}
```

Using ref:

```
static void GetBinaryInput(ref int UserInput)
{ 
  UserInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int UserInput = 0;
  GetBinaryInput(ref UserInput);
  Console.WriteLine(UserInput);
}
```

The first is more conventional and clean for the case in question.

Using an instance variable `UserInput` accessible to all methods is useless too, because this is a parameter between methods interactions, otherwise it is this one that is useless.

Also prefer TryParse to control errors, else use exception handling.

[How TryParse method works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792400/how-tryparse-method-works)

[What's the difference between the 'ref' and 'out' keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388464/whats-the-difference-between-the-ref-and-out-keywords)

[When to use in vs ref vs out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516876/when-to-use-in-vs-ref-vs-out)

[Best practice: ref parameter or return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209476/best-practice-ref-parameter-or-return-value)

[Which is better, return value or out parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810797/which-is-better-return-value-or-out-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

if you're returning a value, you will need the correct type of variable to return it too, e.g:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int output = BinaryInput();
  Console.WriteLine(output);
}

static int BinaryInput()
{
  UserInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  return UserInput;
}
```